# Computing average time given set of start and end dates

Tags: php, mysql, date

I have a table with a field called `date_start` and a field called `date_end` The values of the field are like this

```
year-month-day hours:minutes:seconds
```

I need to find out:

- How much time it to for the person to complete the task.
- The average time it took of all of them.

I'm still a bit new and honestly have no idea where to even start with this.

Thanks for all the help.

Comment: @JYelton Sorry I edited over your revision!

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the fields in MySQL are TIMESTAMP or DATETIME, i'd use two MySQL queries.  One for the task specific results.

```
SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP(date_end) - UNIX_TIMESTAMP(date_start)  AS seconds_to_complete_task
FROM a
```

One for the average result.

```
SELECT AVG(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(date_end)-UNIX_TIMESTAMP(date_start)) AS avg_seconds_to_complete_task
FROM a
```

Answer (score 0):

Start here: strtotime() This function will convert your times to a number representing the number of seconds since 1970. You can then subtract one from the other to find elapsed seconds.

https://www.php.net/strtotime

Comment: what if an application goes into the next day say
date_start = 2009-01-13 18:53:28 
date_end= 2009-01-14 14:39:10

Comment: srtotime("$date_start");
strotime("$date_end");

will that still give me the amount of seconds?

Comment: $num_seconds = strtotime($date_end) - strtotime($date_start);

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested it but this would work:

```
SELECT (UNIX_TIMESTAMP(date_end) - UNIX_TIMESTAMP(date_start)) AS personal_complete_time, 
AVG(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(date_end) - UNIX_TIMESTAMP(date_start)) AS total_average 
FROM mytable
```

You'll get average number of seconds to complete

Answer (score 0):

You say you have a table with dates stored in this format:year-month-day hours:minutes:seconds.

Are you sure you're not using a datetime field? If so, that solves half your problem.  Datetime fields are represented in this manner.

Answer (score 0):

This will work:

```
$total_time_worked = 0;
foreach( $db_records as $time_entry )
{
    $start = strtotime($time_entry['date_start']);
    $end = strtotime($time_entry['date_end']);

    // Time worked (in seconds)
    $worked = $end-$start;

    // Increment the total
    $total_time_worked += $worked;
}

// Get the average time worked (in seconds)
$average = $total_time_worked/count($db_records);
```

Comment: Regardless of the size of the dataset, it's almost surely wiser to put the work into MySQL. This could have very poor performance if the dataset is large.